# Why does [ -f file_name] OR [ -e file_name ] return True if file_name is null?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know `[ -f file ]`, if we use it as a conditional check, checks if *file* is an ordinary file as opposed to a directory or special file; if yes, then the condition becomes true.
Also I Know  `[ -e file ]`  Checks if *file* exists; is true even if *file* is a directory.

Let's say I have some code as below (*saved as `test.sh`*) for checking if its a regular file:

```
    #!/bin/bash 

    file=$1 
    if [ -e $file ] 
    then 
        echo "file exists" 
        if [ -f $file ] 
        then 
            echo "It's a regular file" 
        else 
            echo "It's not a regular file" 
        fi               
    else 
        echo "file doesn't exist" 
    fi
```

And I am running is as below:

```
    ./test.sh /etc/passwd
```

My output is as expected as below:

```
    file exists
    Its a regular file
```

And If I pass a invalid file or directory as argument:

```
    ./test.sh dsdsafds
```

Still the output is as expected:

```
    file doesn't exist
```

But if I am running the script  without  any argument, (meaning `$1` will be null):

```
    ./test.sh
```

Both the `if` conditions are getting satisfied and my output is:

```
    file exists
    Its a regular file
```

Why is it so? Even though `$1` is null, how can `[ -e file ]` and `[ -f file ]` be true?

And is there any way if I can output/print the Boolean values returned by such test operators?

Comment: You have to use if [[ ... ]]. Then it works

Comment: @AndreGelinas This also woked. Thanks for the reply. Didn't notice your reply first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because `[ -f $file ]` becomes `[ -f ]` when `$file` is null, so the expression is always true since `-f` is not a null string. From `man bash`:

   > `test` and `[` evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules based on the number of arguments.
   >
   > 0 arguments
   >           The expression is false.
   >
   > 1 argument
   >           **The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.**
   >
   > 2 arguments
   >           If the first argument is `!`, the expression is true if and only if the second argument is null.  **If the first argument is one of the unary conditional operators listed above under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, the expression is true if the unary test is true.**  If the first argument is not a valid unary conditional operator, the expression is false.
   >
   > ...

   So, quoting the variable `file` prevents the bug you're facing (e.g `[ -f "$file" ]`).
2. `[ ... ] && echo true || echo false`

Comment: It worked and I understood the reason. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: This answer would be better if it referenced or explained how or why such an unintuitive syntax came about.  Or perhaps that's another question...

Comment: @oguzismail, Sorry the edit wasn't satisfactory.  In the last revision was there some reason *not* to cite `info test` as the source of the quote?

Comment: I'd suggest emphasizing that quoting prevents the bug, rather than telling people to quote but leaving its status as a preventative measure implicit.

Comment: @agc, this is a natural consequence of unquoted expansions going through string-splitting and globbing; nobody made an explicit design decision that `test` would have this syntax -- rather, it has the same expansion rules as *every other* regular command going back to the 1970s..